# Loading nulls into bigquery with bq

Tags: google-bigquery

When I use https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert#try-it to upload a JSON file with not all fields inserted in all columns, it is accepted and I get nulls in my data.

When I use bq load and have a schema with mode nullable on possibly missing columns, the same file is rejected because there are different numbers of columns than in the schema.

If I add those columns to the JSON and set them to have a value null, I get an error because bq can't convert that to a string.

If I add those columns to the JSON and set them to have a value '' then the upload proceeds just fine..but now I have empty strings rather than null.  Which is not what I want.

How can I tell the bq tool to let me upload nulls as nulls into a nullable column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, a fix should be out soon.

Comment: any update on this bug? perhaps a link to a bug report?

Comment: This should have been fixed over two years ago. If you continue to see the problem, please let us know (file a bug at the BigQuery issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/)

Answer (score 0):

To import JSON with bq:

Create the table with:

```
bq mk mytemptable schema.json
```

Load data using the JSON flag:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mytemptable users.json
```