# Bigquery Json import from gs, rows with missing fields BUG?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having problem to import data from cloud storage to BigQuery. I get the error because I have record with mising fields.

A developer from google Big Query said that should be fixed soon (it was 8 months ago)

[Loading nulls into bigquery with bq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095128/loading-nulls-into-bigquery-with-bq)

There has been any progress on this ? how do you handle this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data that gets rejected, and the code you are using to load it? This way, it will be easier to understand and reproduce

Comment: Hi Fh, here is the file im trying to import. http://storage.googleapis.com/dummy_dev/users.json.

And the schema of the table is: [{:name=>"id", :type=>:string}, {:name=>"name", :type=>:string}, {:name=>"admin", :type=>:boolean}, {:name=>"phone", :type=>:integer}, {:name=>"created_at", :type=>:timestamp}, {:name=>"updated_at", :type=>:timestamp}, {:name=>"last_name", :type=>:string}]

Comment: Note that the JSON file is generated by an Extract job from api.

I'm using this library: https://github.com/michelson/BigBroda , is an ActiveRecord adapter for ruby/rails and standalone client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
bq mk mytemptable schema.json
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mytemptable users.json
```

Notice that:

- The schema provided in comments is not json, I had to transform the Ruby structure to JSON for this to run).
- When importing JSON, you need to use the "I'm importing JSON" flag.

Comment: Ah, i didn't note the source_format (sourceFormat) option. Thanks a lot @Fh , that solve the issue

Comment: Very timely question and answer because I did not notice where in the BigQuery documentation it specified what kind of schema file you needed to provide. I assumed it was JSON, but the documentation didn't spell that out. Up voting both the Q & A.

Comment: I know, I was confused for a while too. Documentation could be clearer, or the tool smarter about these files. Thanks for the report!